# 404 error when when making POST request in Google SearchAnalytics API

Tags: node.js, google-search-api

I'm trying to make a POST request to get SearchAnalytics data from Google SearchAnalytics API.

I'm getting data from Webmaster API explorer tool. But when I make the same request from Node js I'm getting 404 error.

Below is what I have tried:

```
 request.post({
           headers: {
              'content-type' : 'application/json',
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+access_token
            },
               url:  siteURL,
               json : {
                   'startDate':'2018-06-01',
                   'endDate':'2018-06-22'
               }
            },
            function(error, response, body)
            {
                  console.log('Error - '+error);
                  console.log('Response - '+JSON.stringify(response));
                  console.log('Body - '+body);
                  res.end();
            });
```

Response from Google:

```
  {"statusCode":404,"body":"Not Found",....}
```

Comment: well base on the error it means , your post is missing  `body` , i've never used Google SearchAnalytics API. but maybe try to change `json` to `body` ?

Comment: @feiiiiii Tried it, getting this error `Error - Error: Argument error, options.body.`

Comment: `{body:JSON.stringify(data)}` instead of body: { ....} https://github.com/request/request/issues/1717

Comment: @feiiiiii getting 404 with this

Comment: still body not found ?

Comment: @feiiiiii yes same error

Comment: err , still the format . try `body : JSON.stringify({
                   'startDate':'2018-06-01',
                   'endDate':'2018-06-22'
               })`

Comment: @feiiiiii Still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggle, finally found that the problem was with my `siteURL` variable.

Previous url which did not work

```
var siteURL = 'https://example.com'
```

Working url

```
var siteURL = 'https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com'
```